# Use a Settings bundle to manage preferences from the Settings app

Tags: android, settings

This is a feature that is available in iphone?I want to ask if this feature is available on android phones? and if any tutorial to help get started and implement for your application.

Comment: You should add detailed explanation..!!

Comment: I have an application where I need to add specific fields in settings app, and I can read this fields in my application.

Comment: `accountManager` or `inputmehtodservice`, as I know.